# Create an object within a member function

Tags: c++, class

Create an object within a member function
Savvas · Lecture 12
· 3 hours ago

Hello to all !

I have a class that takes a struct pointer as an argument. Inside a member function of the class, I am creating a new structure and then I try to call other member functions, thatalso take the structure pointer as an argument. When I hit compile I get a compiler error that tells me: "**cannot call member function 'void SearchArray::InsertToTree(Tree*&, int)' (and 'bool SearchArray::IsInTheTree(Tree*, int)') without object**". The struct is not part of the class, but even if I make it part of it, I get the same error.

Here is the function:

```
edit, all the code:

struct Tree{
int item{0};
Tree* left;
Tree* right;

Tree(int val = 0){
    item = val;
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
  }
};

class SearchArray{

public:

void InsertToTree(Tree*& node, int val)
{
    if(node == nullptr)
    {
        node = new Tree(val);
        return;
    }
    else if(val < node->item)
    {
        InsertToTree(node->left, val);
    }
    else
    {
        InsertToTree(node->right, val);
    }

}

bool IsInTheTree(Tree* node, int val)
{
    if(node == nullptr)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(val == node->item) { return true; }
    else if(val < node->item)
    {
        return IsInTheTree(node->left, val);
    }
    else { return IsInTheTree(node->right, val);}
}



static bool Exists(int arr[], int size, int k)
{
    Tree* tree = new Tree;
    tree = nullptr;

     for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
     {
         InsertToTree(tree, arr[i]);
     }

     bool answer = IsInTheTree(tree,k);

     return answer;

     delete tree;
  }
};
```

Have I not created an object already? Thank you for your time!

edit:
I use eclipse under windows 10 with mingw. I have not tested it with VS.

Comment: I was expecting it to be an issue with "pointer to member function" (duplicate) but can't tell from this snippet. Trying to reproduce ... Nope, compile fine when I stub Tree and those two methods.

Comment: What does the first line of your question and the “SS” in your title mean?

Comment: if InsertToTree is a member of Tree, you need to call tree->InsertToTree(arr[i]) although that won't work on nullptr. Don't do new/delete, just create a temporary tree like this: "Tree tree;" and it will be destructed when it goes out of scope (when you exit the function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cannot call member function 'void SearchArray::InsertToTree(Tree*&, int)

This is telling you that `InsertToTree()` is a member function of the `class SearchArray`.  So you'll need to construct an instance of `SearchArray` in order to call that member function, something like:

```
SearchArray mySearchArray; // calls the default constructor, you may need to call a different constructor, i.e. one with arguments
...
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    mySearchArray.InsertToTree(tree, arr[i]);
}
```

and similarilily for `SearchArray::IsInTheTree`,

Comment: Thank you that did it. I did not know you can instantiate a class object inside the class it self. Is this part of recursion? (beginner here)

Comment: Your problem is that `Exists` is `static` so it has no `this` pointer.  Either it shouldn't be `static` or you need create an instance of `SearchArray` in order to call non-`static` member functions of `SearchArray`.